# splitting a string in between some characters and escape sequences using a regex expression

Tags: java, regex, expression

I would just like to ask some help in constructing a regex formula for this example:

```
Brgy. Captain : Kgg. Constancia M. Reyes\nKagawad : Kgg. Henry A. Artisen\n             Kgg. Juliana S. Santos\n                Kgg. Sonia C. Alzona\n              Kgg. Fernandito L. Perez\n              Kgg. Ismael V. Capunitan\n              Kgg. Gregoria R. Sanchez\n              Kgg. Nerisa Maristañes
```

I am using Java in Ecplise IDE. I just would like to get the all the councilor names and then ignore all preceding and succeeding characters. This is what I would like to get:

- Kgg. Constancia M. Reyes
- Kgg. Constancia M. Reyes
- Kgg. Juliana S. Santos
- Kgg. Sonia C. Alzona
- Kgg. Fernandito L. Perez
- Kgg. Ismael V. Capunitan
- Kgg. Gregoria R. Sanchez
- Kgg. Nerisa Maristañes

Is this possible in the first place?

I tried using this regex as i have a google chrome app then can test a regex formula but failed to match it: `(Brgy. Captain :).\\n+(Kagawad :).\\n+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer provided by Justin Pihony matches all of the given councilor names, but the last one. Maybe you tried to remove everything that matches instead of preserving.

```
(\\n.*?)(?=Kgg)
```

This one is the opposite. It matches everything between. But for it to work you have to add another \n to the beginning of the list.

For eclipse I can recommend you the following plug-in for very fast testing of regular expressions: http://myregexp.com/eclipsePlugin.html

And for basic understanding of regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

HTH

Comment: It worked! :) thank you for helping me. i've always had a hard time constructing regex. i'll try to change the strings for them to really match.

Answer (score 1):

If it will always be `Kgg`, then this should work:

```
(Kgg.*?)(?=\\n)
```

Comment: I tried to use your suggestion but what I got was the opposite of what i'd really like to get. i printed the output in console and what i got was 

- Brgy. Captain :
- Kagawad :
- Kgg. Nerisa Maristañes

Comment: Using http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html, this works. You have to iterate the groups. This will place each match into a group